# Saving new Lines in database and Json

Tags: database, json, newline

I have this problem:
I have an HTML textarea which is filled by the user. (And he can press The enter button to go on a new line).
Then I take The value of The textarea using the command:

```
document.getElementById("textareaCommento")
```

And I pass The value to the servlet using an XmlHttpRequest.
In The servlet I  save this value in a database. 
Since this point I have no problems...

Then, in another part I want to get The values from The database. Using a servlet I make this query

```
Select * from comments
```

And I transform the results in json. Here I have The problem... The newline character makes my JSON string invalid. For example:

```
"Comment":"hello
Word"
```

How can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace the `\n` character from database to something like `<br/>`

For the replace see [replace \n and \r\n with <br /> in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056834/replace-n-and-r-n-with-br-in-java)

Comment: \n is the new line character. It is there

Comment: When you query the database the \n and \r chars are also returned. It is very likely that you cannot see them but surely they are there

Comment: really? I did not know! so before putting the string in json format I do character substitution \n with the sequence <br>?

Comment: yes , use the link i gave you ine my answer to replace also \r characters

Comment: ok, the replace works, but when i put the text in a td field of a table, it shows <br/>. it don't go on a new line...:(

Comment: I do the reverse process in the javascript page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18510/discussion-between-mavroscy-and-marty)

Answer (score 2):

this CSS worked for me,

white-space: pre-line;

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to url encode your values so hello world would actually become "hello%20world", to do it in java see here:

[Encoding URL query parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java)

To do it in javascript see here:

[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)