# Re-formating HTML text when sending from JAVA server

Tags: jakarta-ee

After much efforts, I finally have a simple Java server that connects to a browser through HTTPS. User submits a form to the server via browser. The server receives it, process it, and then I need to send back the result text as HTML code. The problem is that my results are formatted in JAVA; new lines are formatted by `\n` and tabs by `\t` as opposed to `<br>` and such, which is not recognized by the browser, and the text is messed up. How can I format the text to be HTML friendly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use regular expressions to find and replace the newline characters with `<br>`. Here's a similar question: [replace \n and \r\n with <br /> in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056834/replace-n-and-r-n-with-br-in-java)