# Android: Format string to html - add new lines <br/>

Tags: java, android, html, string-formatting

I need to format text coming from user to HTML, but the input is multiple line and I have to replace all "enters" from that string to HTML `<br />` tags.

```
String message = messageEditText.getText().toString();
```

This is the message I want to format. How can I format the string accordingly?

Comment: yep, similar problem.. thx

Comment: thanks for my wasted time on this question @Sandak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
message = message.replace ("\\r\\n", "<br>").replace ("\\n", "<br>");
```

Comment: `myString.replace(System.lineSeparator(), "<br>");` could potentially work, but this relies on the separator of the system the application is running on and the user input could be different than that.

Comment: Updated my answer.  If this is not working, please provide more information.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. I love to write this. No, I'm not a nerd yet. This is the new trend. :D

Answer (score 1):

According to your operating system, the string will have newline character/s at the end of each line. Those can be `\n` or `\r\n`. Just write:

```
inputString = inputString.replace("\r\n", "<br />").replace("\n", "<br />");
```

By this, if the current operating system uses `\r\n` those will be replaced within the first replacement, else if it's `\n`, they won't be found in first replacement, but will be replaced within the second one.

If you want to write some **cool** code, you can use the following:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

to get the new-line character/s of the system.

Comment: +1 - Don't really see the reason for a downvote.

Comment: I wrote it with the fury I got from the downvote :) Also I edited the question, I was the first one to point out immutability and even different new-line strings. Accepted answer was only replacing "\r\n" with "<br>". Funny days. Funny. I'm off the work.

Comment: Not the downvoter but, the backslashes will need to be backslashed.

Comment: Please don't get funnier. @ScaryWombat check this one out :D http://stackoverflow.com/a/12053430/1275577

Comment: Wow your nickname IS BackSlash. Thank you guys, you made my day. :D

Comment: You link you gave is using replaceAll which takes a regular expression.

Comment: I'm making jokes here. Whatever.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan Forgive me. I removed the comment, it was totally wrong. `\r\n` was fine, `\\r\\n` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double replacement as already suggested in other responses, but I would tend to prefer regex replacement, for concision of code:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\r?\n", "<br/>");
```

Or, of course Pattern equivalent, if you need to do the operation multiple times:

```
Pattern endOfLine = Pattern.compile("\r?\n");
endOfLine.matcher(yourString).replaceAll("<br/>");
```

Also, be careful with using System's line separator if user's input has been acquired from a web interface, or a remote system (depending on your use case, of course). User may use a different OS...

However, in all cases, make sure you do any EOL -> <br/> replacement, AFTER you have HTML-encoded any special characters in the user's input. Otherwise, the <br> tag will get encoded...