# Line break \n doesn't work, it show as string

Tags: android, string, webview, line-breaks

I have a String with (\n) as a line break

```
String mytext = "<p>Your email is not correct.\nPlease check again</p>"
//(mytext value load from my database)
```

And i put mytext on webview like this :

```
web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", mytext, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

But, i don't know why \n doesn't work as line break, but it show as String "\n"?

How to fix it?

I tried to replace \n with `</ br>` with `mytext.replace("\n","</ br>")` and `mytext.replaceAll("\n", "</ br>")` but it doesn't work.

Thanks

**Updated**

So the solution is :

`mytext.replace ("\\r\\n", "<br>").replace ("\\n", "<br>");`

Thank you, @ChristianJonassen for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You are using HTML, you need to introduce an HTML line break.

In your case, the source code of the page will be given the line break, but not the representation given to the user.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
String mytext = "<p>Your email is not correct.<br />Please check again</p>"
```

Since it comes from an external service, you can edit the String by replacing `\n`:

```
mytext.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: but i can't edit mytext, it load from my office server.

Comment: There is typically a method called "nl2br" (which changes plain newlines to <br>). That might help. :)

Comment: i can't put the original problem here, so i make an example with simple String above.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen : can you give me an example how to use it?

Comment: There are various approaches.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174622/android-format-string-to-html-add-new-lines-br ... or you can Google it further. It's "newline to br" (or newline to HTML linebreak, or whatever).

Comment: @ChristianJonassen : wow...thanks, dude.. so the solution is mytext.replace ("\\r\\n", "<br>").replace ("\\n", "<br>");