# Line break in resources strings doesn't work

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

This question exist two times :

[Line break \n doesn't work, it show as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717311/line-break-n-doesnt-work-it-show-as-string)

[String Resource new line /n not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible)

But neither \n or hit enter in strings.xml gives me a line break in the textView that i set the text.
Does anyone knows why?

My textView:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="952dp"
    android:layout_height="172dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/give_username"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.003" />
```

How i set the text:

```
this.textView.setText(R.string.give_sex_age);
```

The string in resources:

```
<string name="give_sex_age">You are a new user.\nPlease give your sex and your age</string>
```

Comment: If your TextView's `inputType` is set to "text", this may be a reason why the line breaks are ignored. Having said that, some more information (e.g., a concrete example) would help giving a specific answer.

Comment: "But neither \n or hit enter in strings.xml gives me a line break"....give a sample

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @seeming.amusing delete the inputType and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seeming.amusing said in the comments it was the inputType the reason that line break  are ignored. I just delete this line

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

Now it works!

Comment: why would a TextView have an inputType?

Comment: @MartyMiller That was the mistake. A TextView must not have an inputType. But google allows this field for some reason